# Зазноба - озноб: что общего?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Зазноба, как известно, - это предмет любви, как говорится, объект воздыханий. А есть ещё русское слово "озноб", то есть состояние холода при замерзании или при повышенной температуре.
Интересно было бы узнать, что общего между этими словами? Вроде бы от любви не трясет так, как от озноба? )))

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего **зазноба** происходит от слова **зной**, ведь это не просто возлюбленная, а страстная, жаркая и, наконец, **знойная** женщина. Хотя озноб - это не только холод, дрожь, но и болезнь, а страстную любовь иногда называют болезнью. Осталось выяснить, можно ли считать антонимы зной и озноб однокоренными. Есть мнение, что "да". Вот оно:

> Знобить `Этимологический словарь
> русского языка` знобить Искон.
> Происхождение неясно. Несомненно,
> является суф. производным от зноб (или
> знобь, зноба) «чувство холода, озноб».
> Последнее связывают или с зябнуть, что
> очень сомнительно, или со зной «жар»,
> что вероятнее: при лихорадке бросает и
> в жар и в холод (слово зной имело
> раньше, вероятно, и значение «холод»,
> ср. диал. знойко «жарко» и «холодно»).
> К развитию противоположных значений
> см. урод и уродился, конец и начало и
> т. д. Школьный этимологический словарь
> русского языка. Происхождение слов. —
> М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва

Answer (score 0):

Этимологический словарь Крылова не согласен со словарём Шанского -  из статьи следует, что "зазноба" и "озноб" таки однокоренные:

[**ЗАЗНОБА**](http://enc-dic.com/krylov/Zaznoba-2713.html)

> Это слово в значении "любимый человек" проникло в литературный язык из
>   диалектов и является производным от глагола ***зазнобиться*** –
>   "влюбиться", восходящего к глаголу знобить, имеющему значение
>   "холодить". Исходное значение существительного зазноба, таким образом,
>   "то, от чего бросает в холод".

У того же Шанского есть тому почти дословное подтверждение:

> **Зазно́ба** (любовь, любимый человек). Собственно русское. В русский  литературный язык пришло из диалектов в XIX в. Является безаффиксным 
>   производным от ***зазнобиться*** — «влюбиться» (ср. диалектное ***зазной***
>   —  «любовь, зазноба» от ***зазноиться*** — «влюбиться»). Глаголы
>   ***зазнобиться, зазноиться*** восходят соответственно к словам ***знобить*** и ***зноить*** — «жечь, жарить, припекать». ***Зазноба*** первоначально — «чувство, бросающее в холод» (в жар—зазной), затем — «вызывающий это чувство человек». Ср. аналогичное
>   по внутренней форме вульгарно-грубое ***задрыга***.

[Краткий этимологический словарь русского  языка. - H. M. Шанский, В. В. Иванов, Т. В.  Шанская, 1971 г.](http://educador.narod.ru/index/slovo_zaznoba/0-451)

Читаем у Даля:

[**ЗНОБИТЬ**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/245514)

> что, кого, холодить, студить, морозить; безл. быть морозу. Чем знобить
>   кучера у подъезда. отпустил бы его домой. На дворе знобит. Меня
>   знобит, мне холодно. Лихорадка знобит, трясет, бьет. Знобить рыбу,
>   морозить. Знобить пашню или зябь, пахать с осени под яровое, чтобы
>   пахота в зиму промерзла. -ся, страд. и ·возвр. по смыслу речи.
>
> | Знобиться по ком, пск., твер. беспокоиться и заботиться, жалеть и
>   грустить.

Любопытно это последнее - "знобиться по ком"...

И ещё из Даля же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам Владимир Иванович не уверен, что "зазноба" имеет прямое отношение к глаголу ***знеять...***

> Знёять и знеять, з н ё е т, несов., неперех.
>
> 1. Знёять. Чуть чуть гореть, тлеть. Тряпица знеет. Арх., Даль. Черепов. Новг.
> 2. Блестеть, пламенеть, краснеть (о раскаленном металле). = З н ё я т ь. Расплавленная медь знеет в горне.

Answer (score -1):

Зазноба - это та, от которой знобит, т. е. бросает в жар; так что тут всё нормально.

Comment: А что именно "нормально"?